# Does sleep work right in a sidekiq worker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have sidekiq worker which executes http requests and updates database, and I'm using `sleep` inside methods which executed by worker. `sleep` needs to prevent to often http requests, but it looks like sleep doesn't works as expected. For example I have one http request, which gets some data and save that data to the database and then `sleep 2`, but data saves more quickly than 1 record per 2 
seconds.

P.S. I need delay exactly in jobs (not between them) because one worker performs multiple http requests at one job execution, and I need delay between each http request.

Comment: According to Sidekiq's author, [it works fine](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/3199#issuecomment-255199576). My experience is the same. Are you sure you don't have many workers spawning in parallel and frequent saves coming from that?

Comment: @katafrakt, Yes thats weird behavior is observed when worker runs in 5 threads, with 1 thread `sleep` behavior is close to expected. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 3):

`sleep` pauses that Thread only.  Other threads will execute other jobs, possibly making other HTTP calls concurrently.  If this is a problem, you need to use a rate limiter or schedule your jobs (e.g. 1 per second) to minimize concurrency.